# Late contract package

Tags: human-resources, job-change, contracts, benefits

I have been working for my company for a year part-time, but I have got a promotion to become a full-time worker. My company had been applying the new hourly rate, but it has been over two weeks without receiving the official contract and packages. I contacted HR and found out that they have been delaying my process because someone left the HR without finishing my paperwork. 
I wanted to get the full benefit (especially health insurance) set up quick by signing contract as soon as I receive it, but it’s been delayed.  Can I ask my company to compensate for the delay?

Comment: Compensate in what way? You're already getting the new hourly rate, right? What do you want them to compensate you for?

Answer (score 2):

> *I wanted to get the full benefit (especially health insurance) set up quick by signing contract as soon as I receive it, but it’s been delayed. Can I ask my company to compensate for the delay?*

Well, based on *your* description, I think you're asking the wrong question. In case you want to ensure the *benefits* are given to you as soon as possible, you should work to make those become applicable, i.e., ask the HR department to move your paperwork faster and get that completed.

As far as I can understand, it's not very clear for to me for exactly what you're asking to be "compensated". If you're not covered under the health insurance policies, the best way to get "compensated" is to make sure you're covered sooner than later. Any other form of compensation is not likely to be a real "compensation", *per se*.

Note: The department already informed you of the reason and unless you have another valid reason (preferably with proof) to believe otherwise, you should follow up with them to get the paperwork completed, not seeking "compensation". I can understand, but "unforeseen delays" happens, that's the real life. Not to get "fierce"/"upset"/"angry" if it's happening only once, for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with this, I apply my compensation based on my contribution to the company as I still not received my offer. I request politely to my HR asking for compensation. You need to have a black and white letter to request compensation.

It is unpleasant for HR to do that, I know. But it's not an excuse for them to delay your offer. There is lots of benefit difference between part-time and full-time work and it is important for you. It also up to your personal judgment whether you seek to demand compensation. You can certainly politely request it. But if you choose to force it, you may risk damaging your relationship with HR. If you feel your decision is right, you should ask for. So it's a personal decision up to your discretion.